# Checking whether ComboBox contains item that is read from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have got this `SqlCommand` that `selects` item in`combo-box` depending on what was `read` from database.

The combo-box contains 4 values. (one of them should be selected)

I have an issue because I need to check whether the value which is being read from SQL DB is one of the combo-box items.

May I ask how the code should look like?

```
SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM client WHERE ID_K='" + choose_id + "'", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader read= command.ExecuteReader();

if (read.Read())
{
     if (read["price"] != DBNull.Value)
     {
         cb_choose_price.SelectedItem = read.GetString(read.GetOrdinal("price"));
     }} con.Close();
```

Comment: Could you translate your members' names to english when you are asking on the english speaking website? It would help others to understand your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` property of a combobox component binds to an actual object stored in it (or rather references to these objects). If you want to set a selected item by a displayed string you have to get a collection of items, cast them to string and then select appropriate item. Check out my code sample for the Person type.

When you bind a combobox to a datasource it displays referred objects using ToString() method. For example:

```
class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}

var persons = new List<Person> { 
    new Person("Adam", 10), 
    new Person("Thomas", 20) };
comboBox.DataSource = persons;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

comboBox.SelectedItem = "Adam"; // this will not display a person named Thomas because the combobox is binded to the Person type
comboBox.SelectedItem = persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Thomas").Single(); // this will show Adam if it is available in the comboBox
```

**UPDATE based on the comment:**

> I think I understand all of that but is there any way to check whether the item 
>   that should be selected (the string from SQL DB) even exists in the list of 
>   items in combobox?

```
var item = comboBox1.Items.Cast<Person>();
bool isThereAdam = item.Any(i => i.Name == "Adam");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time. I think I understand all of that but is there any way to check whether the item that should be selected (the string from SQL DB) even exists in the list of items in combobox?

Comment: Don't you think that this: `cb_vyber_cena.Items.Contains(precti.GetString(precti.GetOrdinal("price")))` might solve the issue?

Comment: It depends on whether there are stored strings in the combobox. If there are objects of another type and the price is just a property of one of them, this would fail.

Comment: I edited my answer. I got it partially wrong with the SelectedText property.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your will to enlighten me. Your post helped me alot. Hope this won't be flagged as "too chatty" comment :) .

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing data binding using a DataTable, this should work:

```
private void BindClientCombobox(DataTable clientDataTable)
{
    this.cbClients.DataSource = clientDataTable;
    this.cbClients.ValueMember = "client_id";
    this.cbClients.DisplayMember = "client_name";
}

private bool ContainsClientID(int clientID)
{
    return this.cbClients.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Any(drv => (int)drv.Row.ItemArray[0] == clientID);
}

private bool ContainsClientName(string clientName)
{
    return this.cbClients.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Any(drv => (string)drv.Row.ItemArray[1] == clientName);
}
```